# Output formate changed java

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans

I am new in **Java**. I am trying to learn to make some view in **javafx**. Here, I am trying to write some simple code to create button in a scene. Button is created successfully but the issue is not showing output properly. And I don't know how to search this type of issue but I look javafx documents. But, didn't find any solution.
Here is my code.

```
public class PlayingCard extends Application {

    @Override 
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        System.out.println("hello world");

        primaryStage.setTitle("Button Title");

        Button btn = new Button("Click HERE");
        StackPane layout = new StackPane();
        layout.getChildren().add(btn);

        Scene scena = new Scene(layout, 600, 300);
        primaryStage.setScene(scena);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

I know there is nothing wrong in the code. I missed some setting. Here I am posting output screenshot. [image]
And addition, when I add imageview with some image the same thing like output was not shown.

Comment: That code works fine for me.  Perhaps it's some kind of font or localization issue?

Comment: Yes, I think so, that's why I posted here if anyone is going through this issue. They can help me. Thank you